# Overlay Image in OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing

I am trying to overlay an image over the video capture of my program with OpenCV but I am having trouble getting it to work. I set the a region of interest in the original frame taken from the webcam in the form of a rectangle. Then i copy it to the original frame. However it never shows up on the new frame captured by the webcam. I tested it and the image is loading correctly but it is not being copied to the new frame for some reason.

Code Below in C++:

```
#include<opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include<opencv2/contrib/contrib.hpp>
#include<opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include<opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

int main(){
    VideoCapture cap;
    cap.open(0);

    if(!cap.isOpened()){
        cerr << "Error opening the webcam!" << endl;
        return -1;
    }


    for(;;){
        Mat frame;

        cap>>frame; 

        Mat newFrame;
        frame.copyTo(newFrame);

        Mat image = imread("C:\\User\\Desktop\\images\\image.png");


    int cx = (newFrame.cols - 70) / 2;
        if (image.data) {
            // Get a BGR version of the face, since the output is BGR color
            Mat srcBGR = Mat(face.size(), CV_8UC3);
            cvtColor(image, srcBGR, CV_GRAY2BGR);
            // Get the destination ROI (and make sure it is within the image)
            Rect dstRC = Rect(cx, newFrame.rows/2, 70, 70);
            Mat dstROI = newFrame(dstRC);
            // Copy the pixels from src to dst.
            srcBGR.copyTo(dstROI);
        }


        imshow("frame", newFrame);
        char key = (char) waitKey(30);
        // Exit this loop on escape:
        if(key == 27)
            break;
    }   

    return 0;
}
```

Any suggestions or help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You converted image to BGR by using not converted one:
change this: image.copyTo(dstROI); to this srcBGR.copyTo(dstROI);

```
#include<opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include<opencv2/contrib/contrib.hpp>
#include<opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include<opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

int main(){
    VideoCapture cap;
    cap.open(0);

    if(!cap.isOpened()){
        cerr << "Error opening the webcam!" << endl;
        return -1;
    }
    Mat image = imread("D:\\ImagesForTest\\Lena.jpg",0);
    cv::resize(image,image,Size(70,70));  
    Mat frame;
    for(;;){
        cap>>frame; 
        Mat newFrame=frame.clone();
        int cx = (newFrame.cols - 70) / 2;
        if (!image.empty()) {
            // Get a BGR version of the face, since the output is BGR color
            Mat srcBGR = Mat(image.size(), CV_8UC3);
            cvtColor(image, srcBGR, CV_GRAY2BGR);
            // Get the destination ROI (and make sure it is within the image)
            Rect dstRC = Rect(cx, newFrame.rows/2, 70, 70);
            Mat dstROI = newFrame(dstRC);
            // Copy the pixels from src to dst.
            srcBGR.copyTo(dstROI);
        }
        imshow("frame", newFrame);
        char key = (char) waitKey(30);
        // Exit this loop on escape:
        if(key == 27)
            break;
    }   

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Actually that's the way I had it before and it didn't work. I was testing it another way and forgot to change it back. I just changed it in the sample code back to srcBGR.copyTo(dstROI)

Comment: Ok, I have edited my answer, I have tested this code and it works.

Comment: Thanks. The problem was that i was not re-sizing the image according to the destination size. Thanks again.

Comment: Elegant solution. What about images with alpha channels, e.g. png?

Comment: Split image, extract alpha, convert to float and 0-1 range elements, then blend images using these coefficients: Vec3f r = v1f*blending_coeff + (1.0 - blending_coeff)*v2f; where r - resulting pixel, v1f - pixel of one image to blend, v2f - pixel of the second image to blend. It can be done pixel by pixel or using matrix mul and + operators.